# MBProgressHUD not hiding - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, swift3, mbprogresshud

I am trying to show `MBProgressHUD` on `UIWebView`. I am trying to load an iframe in webview. My spinner shows when webview starts loading, but doesn't hide even though it goes to the breakpoint in the `webView didFinishLoad()`.

Here is my code :

```
class LiveViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var liveWebView: UIWebView!

var spinnerActivity: MBProgressHUD! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    liveWebView.delegate = self

    let embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe src=\"\" width=\"100%\" height=\"500\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe></body></html>" //link removed
    liveWebView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: nil)
}

public func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
    spinnerActivity = MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
    spinnerActivity.label.text = "Loading"
    spinnerActivity.detailsLabel.text = "Please Wait!"
    spinnerActivity.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}

public func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
    spinnerActivity.hide(animated: true)
}

public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error){
    spinnerActivity.hide(animated: true)
}
}
```

I noticed that webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad is being called twice.
Please help me. The spinner is just not hiding.. I have used Xcode8 and Swift 3.

Edit :

I tried this but it doesn't work too :

```
class LiveViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var liveWebView: UIWebView!

var spinnerActivity: MBProgressHUD! = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    liveWebView.delegate = self

    let embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe src=\"\" width=\"100%\" height=\"500\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe></body></html>" //link removed
    liveWebView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: nil)
}

    public func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)

    }

    public func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)

    }

    public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error){
        MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
    }
}
```

See [image: This]

Comment: Where are you hiding it?

Comment: @User511 in webView didFailLoadWithError and webViewDidFinishLoad

Comment: Yes I saw that check my answer. Hide it like I have mentioned.

Comment: In webviewdidfinishload set spinnerActivity = nil;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace your code by this :

```
class LiveViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {
    var isHudShow  = false
    @IBOutlet weak var liveWebView: UIWebView!

    var spinnerActivity: MBProgressHUD! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        liveWebView.delegate = self
        let embededHTML = "<html><body><iframe src=\"\" width=\"100%\" height=\"500\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\"></iframe></body></html>" //link removed
        liveWebView.loadHTMLString(embededHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }

    public func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
     if isHudShow == false
      {
        MBProgressHUD.showAdded(to: self.view, animated: true)
        isHudShow =true
      }

    }

    public func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView){
     MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
    }

    public func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, didFailLoadWithError error: Error){
     MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: MBProgressHUD.hide(animated:true) gives an error saying Missing Argument for parameter 'for'